# I cant create events with Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Graph API to create and get events from facebook.
Try in various ways but always get the same results. In the case of creating an event I get an ID, but the event never see in my account. When trying to get my events always get an empty array.
Try a query with fql.query but got the same result, then tested my app in the following query and got what he wanted.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Someone can help me. Thank you very much.

This is how I'm doing

**Create Event**

```
FB.api('/me/events', 'POST', {
        name: "Evento desde mi app",
        start_time: d1,
        //end_time: d2,
        location: "En Quilmes"
    }, function (res) {
        console.log(res);

    });
```

**Get Events**

```
FB.api('me/events',function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
    });

FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid = xxxxxxx) AND creator = xxxxxxx'

        },function(response) { 
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
```

Comment: do you have the permissions to read events?

Comment: Yes I have user_events and create_event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could create an event, I still can not get my events.
Try adding the access token but I get an empty array.

This is the code to create an event

```
        var accessToken =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
    var name = "My Event";
    var startTime = "07/29/2012 12:00 PM";
    var endTime = "07/29/2012 06:00 PM";
    var location = "Argentina";
    var description = "description";

    var eventData = {
        "access_token": accessToken,
        "start_time" : startTime,
        "end_time":endTime,
        "location" : location,
        "name" : name,
        "description":description,
        "privacy":"OPEN"
    };
    FB.api("/me/events",'post',eventData,function(response2){
        console.log(response2);
    });
```

Comment: could you send me a few of the event id's you have created with this method please.

Comment: i am able to access your event with my app id,  see here: http://anotherfeed.com/curl.api.php?objid=399255180132883  using cURL php.  try setting access token to your app's access token.

Comment: I could also get an event from javascript having the ID.The problem I have is that I can not get all my events.

Comment: Shawn Thanks for the help they are giving me, I apologize if my English is not good.

Comment: I did the test to enter the following url from my browser and I get all my events.
https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx/events?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Then try a Get of that url in my code and got the same empty array

var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx/events?access_token="+access_token , false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);

Answer (score 0):

> Event GETs from Graph API/FQL Will Require an Access Token

All calls to get events from the Graph API or FQL will now require an access token to be used.

**As announced by Facebook:** https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: I checked the network in chrome inspector and I see that I'm sending the Acces Tocken
Query String parameters
access_token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
method:get
pretty:0
sdk:joey
callback:FB._callbacks.__gcb2

Is this correct?

Comment: if the array is always comming up empty i would suggest searching and or creating a bug for this.